# setTimeout and scheduling of the function call

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Given the following code, when will function `go` be executed?

```
setTimeout(go, 0);
```

Will it be added to the end of the Job Queue immediately, or added to the end of the Job Queue after the minimum interval for `setTimeout`?

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: I thing in the next event loop.

Comment: It likely depends on browser implementation. In chrome, it seems to be added after exactly 2ms. I couldn't get consistent results in firefox, sometimes it ran as fast as 1.25ms, throwing 2ms out the window. http://jsfiddle.net/q2tf393g/

Comment: The documentation says 4ms, but based on the above test, i don't think it is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers implement a minimum delay time of 4ms. You can use lower values without error, but when actually executing the script, the browser will overwrite the timeout value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers

Comment: Another good explanation can be found [here](http://geekabyte.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/javascript-effect-of-setting-settimeout.html)

Answer (score 0):

with a timeout of 0, it will be added to the end of the job queue immediately

Comment: Can you provide a source?